# Help needed to interpret the ACF plot

Tags: interpretation, autocorrelation

[image: ACF plot(lag is in weeks)]

Unit of lag: 1 week

Y-axis: sales

Can someone please help me to interpret this plot?

Answer (score -1):

It could be a (1,0,0)(0,1,0)52  or a (1,1,0)(0,1,0)52 or perhaps a model requiring a quarterly effect or a model with 51 dummy weekly indicators or some other model as only the data knows for sure and it should be allowed to speak. There may be level shifts and/or time trends and of course possible one-time anomalies/pulses. There may be non-constant error variance and/or non-constant parameters. There may be holiday effects. The ACF is descriptive and different structure/models can have similar looking acf's. If you post your data including country of origin, I will attempt to help identify the underlying model.

Comment: Because the question is about how to interpret this kind of plot, information about how to do that generally would be more useful to most readers.

Comment: The general approach is to examine the degree/speed of decay of both the ACF and PACF . Just using either one is like trying to dance with one leg ...very difficult.